# Update rows of pandas dataframe based upon other rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe which has the following columns ( pk1, pk2 type,  qty_6,  qty_7 ). I have type as predicted_90, override_90, predicted_50, override 50. Now Based upon combination of pk1 and pk2 If for type predicted_50, predicted_90 contains some value for override_50, override_90 apart from NaN, I want to update my dataframe columns predicted_50, predicted_90 with override_50 and override_90 respectively. Also, I want to capture this change in a boolean column called qty_6_overridden, qty_7_overridden. Also, I want to capture the difference between the both in a column qty_6_dev, qty_7_dev.
qty_6_dev = qty_6 override - qty_6 predicted

Example dataframe :

```
data=[
['B01FV0FBX4','2019-01-13','predicted_90',2207.931,2217.841],
['B01FV0FBX4','2019-01-13','predicted_50',1561.033,1521.567],
['B01FV0FBX4','2019-01-13','override_90',1973.000,np.NaN],
['B01FV0FBX4','2019-01-13','override_50',1233.000,np.NaN],
['B01FV0FBX4','2019-01-06','override_50',np.NaN,1233.000],
['B01FV0FBX4','2019-01-06','predicted_50',1210.129,1213.803],
['B01FV0FBX4','2019-01-06','override_90',np.NaN,1973.000],
['B01FV0FBX4','2019-01-06','predicted_90',1911.205,1921.594]
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['pk1','pk2', 'type', 'qty_6', 'qty_7'])
```

Expected output :

```
data=[
['B01FV0FBX4','2019-01-13','predicted_90',1973.000,2217.841,-234.931,0,True,False],
['B01FV0FBX4','2019-01-13','predicted_50',1233.000,1521.567,-328.033,0,True,False],
['B01FV0FBX4','2019-01-13','override_90',1973.000,np.NaN,0,0,False,False],
['B01FV0FBX4','2019-01-13','override_50',1233.000,np.NaN,0,0,False,False],
['B01FV0FBX4','2019-01-06','override_50',np.NaN,1233.000,0,0,False,False],
['B01FV0FBX4','2019-01-06','predicted_50',1210.129,1213.000,0,-0.803,False,True],
['B01FV0FBX4','2019-01-06','override_90',np.NaN,1973.000,0,0,False,False],
['B01FV0FBX4','2019-01-06','predicted_90',1911.205,1973.000,0,51.406,False,True]
]
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['pk1','pk2', 'type', 'qty_6', 'qty_7','qty_6_dev','qty_7_dev', 'qty_6_overridden','qty_7_overridden'])
```

In the example you can see, the quantities with override exchange quantitties with predicted and we get the corresponding columns 'qty_6_dev','qty_7_dev', 'qty_6_overridden','qty_7_overridden'.

I was able to write a solution. It works but it looks horrible and very difficult to understand for others.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import math

data=[
['B01FV0FBX4','2019-01-13','predicted_90',2207.931,2217.841],
['B01FV0FBX4','2019-01-13','predicted_50',1561.033,1521.567],
['B01FV0FBX4','2019-01-13','override_90',1973.000,np.NaN],
['B01FV0FBX4','2019-01-13','override_50',1233.000,np.NaN],
['B01FV0FBX4','2019-01-06','override_50',np.NaN,1233.000],
['B01FV0FBX4','2019-01-06','predicted_50',1210.129,1213.803],
['B01FV0FBX4','2019-01-06','override_90',np.NaN,1973.000],
['B01FV0FBX4','2019-01-06','predicted_90',1911.205,1921.594]
]
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['pk1','pk2', 'type', 'qty_6', 'qty_7'])

override_map = {
    "predicted_50" : "override_50",
    "predicted_90" : "override_90"
}

def transform_df(df):
    transformed_df = pd.DataFrame()
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        row_type = row['type']
        row_pk1 = row['pk1']
        row_pk2 = row['pk2']

        if row_type in override_map.keys():
            override_type = override_map.get(row_type)
        else:
            for i in range(6,8):
                qty_dev_col = 'qty_'+str(i)+'_dev'
                qty_override_col = 'qty_'+str(i)+'_overridden'
                row[qty_dev_col] = 0
                row[qty_override_col] = False
            transformed_df=transformed_df.append(row, ignore_index=True)
            continue
        corr_df = df.loc[(df.type == override_type) 
                         & (df.pk1 == row_pk1) 
                         & (df.pk2 == row_pk2)]

        for i in range(6,8):
            qty_col = 'qty_'+str(i)
            qty_dev_col = 'qty_'+str(i)+'_dev'
            qty_override_col = 'qty_'+str(i)+'_overridden'
            if not (math.isnan(corr_df[qty_col])) and (corr_df[qty_col].values[0] != row[qty_col]):
                row[qty_dev_col] = corr_df[qty_col].values[0] - row[qty_col]
                row[qty_col] = corr_df[qty_col].values[0]
                row[qty_override_col] = True
            else:
                row[qty_dev_col] = 0
                row[qty_override_col] = False
        transformed_df=transformed_df.append(row, ignore_index=True)
    return transformed_df

x1 = transform_df(df)
```

Is there a better way to do this using lambdas or something ? Also this takes like forever to run over a bigger dataframe.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried using groupBy but am not able to get the logic correct.

Comment: I added a solution which i was able to make. It works but code looks horrible. I am new to python so could not use it well.